# How to debug multithreaded midlet app in EclipseMe?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, java-me, midlet, eclipseme

When debugging multithreaded midlet in the EclipseMe, the breakpoints work for me only in the main thread but not I other threads. Any ideas?

Comment: It's strange, i work with J2ME and Eclipse and i'm always able to set breakpoints within code. Maybe you don't start your threads correctly?

Comment: if you need a answer, i spend a bounty...?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, have you tried putting Thread.sleep() in the main thread and see whether the debugger enters the other thread!